# Ionic capacitor Splash screen doesn’t work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I’m trying to custom my splash screen for my ionic project capacitor and angular based. After change it in the assets of xcode, it works in virtual machine only, but on the real deploy doesn’t work. I’ve try to delete app from the phone too.

Comment: What is the problem? Is the splashscreen not showing or not hiding or is it the wrong image...

Comment: Can you provide more information like what you changed in the assets ?

Comment: Resolved! The problem was the iPhone cache, i've resolved uninstalling the app, turn off the phone and re-do it the build